# Query.setparameter using TemporalTipe.Time

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql

I wanna do `SELECT e FROM Pedidos e WHERE e.diaPedido = :diaPedido AND e.horaPedido = :horaPedido`.
 When I write parameters use `query.setParameter("diaPedido", fechaEscogida, TemporalTipe.DATE)` and `query.setParameter("horaPedido", horaEscogida, TemporalTipe.TIME)` but i don´t know why second filter `Temporal.TIME` doesn´t work because still compare like **TIMESTAMP**.
I use **eclipseLink 2.3.0** and **javax.persistence 2.0.1**.
**diaPedido** and **horaPedido** are both Date in oracle database.

Comment: TemporalType.TIME forces JPA to use your java.util.Date as if it were a java.sql.Time.  You haven't mentioned the issue you are getting, but Time doesn't have date information, only the time portion.  Using your Time with equality to the DATE type will not work if there is date information in the date object.  Try looking at what is in the database and what you are issuing to see for yourself - turn on EclipseLink logging to fine to get the SQL printed off.  Chances are you should be using TemporalType.Date.

Comment: But I just wanna compare hours:minutes:seconds not all Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just compare the time portion of a TIMESTAMP column, you need to use a database function.

In EclipseLink (>=2.4) you can use EXTRACT or CAST, or the FUNCTION/FUNC operator to call a database function.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html

Comment: When I use **CAST** give me error because `CAST('horaPedido', AS TIME)` say me that **horaPedido** is not a **NUMBER**. And How I can extract **TIME**  `EXTRACT(TIME, e.horaPedido)`